# Creating Linear layout with Horizontal scroll view at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a 5x5 table with buttons that take 70% of the space Of the screen. Below this i want to put buttons horizontally with a scrollbar (at the bottom of the screen that means).
The java and xml files are shown below. 
On the output screen i can only see the 5x5 table created and the bottom space is left blank. I am new to android and layout so please help me with this. Thanks!

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
</TableLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsvMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">          

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>     
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Java file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.match_main_skl);
    table = new TableLayout (this);
    setControls();

    hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainTable();
}

private void setControls()
{
    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainPage);
    hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsvMain);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_ll);

}

private void mainTable()
{
    //find screen size of the device (supports all versions)
    Point windowSize = MAUIUtil.GetDefaultWindowSize(this);  
    int cellSize;
    if (windowSize.x >= 0.70 * windowSize.y)
        cellSize = windowSize.x / numColumns;
        else cellSize = (int) ((0.70*windowSize.y)/numColumns);


**//5x5 TABLE**
    TableRow.LayoutParams buttonRow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    buttonRow.height = cellSize * numRows;
    //buttonRow.height = windowSize.x;
    table.setLayoutParams(buttonRow);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);


    for(int rw = 0; rw < numRows; rw++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); //setPadding(left,top,right,bottom)
        row.setId(ROW_ID_OFFSET + rw);//giving each row an id

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tbLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1.0f);
        tbLp.height = cellSize;
        table.setLayoutParams(tbLp);

        for(int col = 0; col < numColumns; col++)
        {
            int btnID = COLUMN_ID_OFFSET + (numColumns * (rw - 1)) +  col;

            //Adding buttons
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setId(btnID);
            btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            btn.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            btn.setText(Integer.toString(btnID));

            row.addView(btn);   
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }

    **//LAST SCROLLABLE HORIZONTAL ROW**

    hsv.addView(ll);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    llp.height = windowSize.y - cellSize;
    hsv.setLayoutParams(llp);

    LinearLayout sll = new LinearLayout(this);

    for(int col = 0; col < scrNumColumns; col++)
    {
        int btnID = SCROLL_COLUMN_ID_OFFSET + col;

        //Adding buttons
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(btnID);
        btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        btn.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        btn.setText(Integer.toString(btnID));

        sll.addView(btn);   
        sll.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } 
    ll.addView(sll);
 }
```

Comment: try giving Layout_weight for tableLayout as .7 and for linearLayout .3

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you created a new LinearLayout and a new HorizontalScrollView after you called findViewById() in the onCreate() method. So you are operating the new created views rather than the views defined in the .xml file.

Try delete these rows:

```
hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
```

Comment: use android:alain_parentBottom="true" in linear layout.and you will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.I have implemented it as you have described.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 


 >

<TableLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

  <TableRow > </TableRow>
  <TableRow > </TableRow>
  <TableRow > </TableRow>
  <TableRow > </TableRow>
  <TableRow > </TableRow>


 </TableLayout>   

<HorizontalScrollView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

 <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button1"/>
  <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button2"/>

   <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button3"/>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button4"/>

     <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button5"/>


       </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help.You can ask if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:alain_parentBottom="true"` in linear layout.and you will achieve what you want.